# How to remove apps which doesn't allow uninstall option without rooting smartphone?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, bloatware

I'm using Samsung J7Max recently I updated MY AIRTEL app and try to uninstall it app uninstalled but leaves an duplicate MY AIRTEL app which tell me download MY AIRTEL app from playstore. I can't remove it or disable it. Don't know what to do. Here is snapshot of duplicate Airtel app.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is airtel app was there on first boot? Did you install airtel app from Playstore OR by downloaded apk? Please explain how you installed that app. It seems like airtel app is a system app.

Comment: I always install apps from Google playstore..

Comment: I want to get rid of it.. help me remove it.

Comment: do you remember that it was there on first boot? System apps are built-in apps like Google. You cannot uninstall them.

Comment: I think no. I have checked.

Comment: After purchase, you open the box and turn on. You can see apps like Google, gmail, Web browser, camera etc. Have you noticed airtel app along with this?

Comment: No it is not pre-installed app. I have uninstalled many time Airtel app but nothing leave app like this. I'm sure.

Comment: May be a factory reset solve this. Backup data before reset. Otherwise please wait for a good answer.

Comment: I think I should wait..

Comment: Even I scanned with  JIO security (norton antivirus) but nothing cames out.

Comment: If it is installed as system app (and not being able to uninstall suggests that), it cannot be removed without root powers (or flashing a clean ROM that comes without it).

Comment: @Ashish Try this: https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand :

- MY AIRTEL is a *system application* that's installed in the `/system`
  partition
- Updates to this app are stored in the `/data` partition

*Without* rooting your phone, you only have *read* access to `/system`, and read/write access to `/data`. That's why you can uninstall MY AIRTEL updates (which are in `/data`), but not the app itself (which is in `/system`). And since Google Play has a newer version, you'll be prompted to update it again, etc.

Rooting your phone will allow you to gain write access to `/system` and hence uninstall any system application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically asks for a no-root solution, which is difficult but not impossible if you are willing to use a temporary root through ADB.
Connect to your device via adb and enter adb root, mount the system partition, and delete the APK thats in your system partition.
This may not work for all devices, as it can be difficult to get true root in production build on many devices. good luck.